# How do I pass data between activities when I press back button in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I'm trying to send data between activities using:

**on Activity 2**

```
Bundle bloc = new Bundle();
bloc.putString("DataLoc", et1.getText().toString());
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);

intent.putExtras(bloc);
```

**on Activity 1**

```
Intent iinf = getIntent();
Bundle binf = iinf.getExtras();

if (binf != null) {
  String data = binf.getString("DataInf");
  tv_1.setText(data);
  tv_1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("DataInf"));

}// end if
```

**My Problem**

I'm on `Activity2` (with `Activity1 under Activity2` opened), when I press back button I need show bundle on one TextView, EditText or similar but only I get to show `onCreate` method.

I try using `onResume` and `onRestart`  but... impossible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I pass data between activities when I press back button in
>   Android?

Start second Activity using [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and use `onActivityResult` in parent Activity for updating `TextView` using received from second Activity

In Second Activity override `onBackPressed()` method and call `setResult` for send data using Intent:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        // add data to Intent 
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
       super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onActivityResult();`

For Sending

```
Intent in= new Intent();

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, in);
finish();

For Recieving

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
    case (abc) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      // your stuff
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` methods. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) you can find an example how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'DataLoc' string to get back the required value in the activity. You must use startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() methods and get the value back using setResult() method.