# Switching between activities without losing data

Tags: android

I keep losing data when pressing the back button after going back from activity 2 to 1.

when passing the data to activity 2 I'm using

```
   intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondactivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

to launch the second activity. is it possible not to lose the data without using sharedpreference when pressing the back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your data in the Application class and use it everywhere

Create a class:

```
public class MyCustomApplication extends Application {
   String myData = "";
}
```

in manifest add class name as android:name

```
<application 
   android:name=".MyCustomApplication"
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
...>
```

access it like this from any activity

```
 String myData = ((MyCustomApplication)getApplication()).myData; 
((MyCustomApplication)getApplication()).myData = "new value";
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new class

```
public class myClass{
    public static String myData;
}
```

In your activity

```
myClass.myData = "Set a text";
```

Then call it everywhere in you activity

```
String myData = myClass.myData;
```

Comment: Im sorry ? why vote down ?

Answer (score -1):

When launching your second activity, you can specify that you are expecting a result from the activity:

```
int LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY);
```

Then, in your second activity, you can override the `onBackPressed()`

> ```
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>     Intent data = new Intent();
>     // add data to Intent 
>     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
>    super.onBackPressed(); }
> ```

Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities when I press back button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206186/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-when-i-press-back-button-in-android)